# Latency in sound playback based on gpio trigger

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, audio-playback

I was following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/gpio-music-box/worksheet/) guide to learn how to trigger sound with the GPIO input.
What I learned is that there is some latency between the press of the button and the played sound. Is it possible to play the sound immediately? Like reading it into a buffer and play from there?
If yes, what is the best practice to achieve this result? I am working with a Pi 2B, language can be anything, I am flexible. Any guideance is appreciated.

To be more specific, this is the Python code I ended up with:

```
import pygame.mixer
from pygame.mixer import Sound
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

button = Button(3)
pygame.mixer.init()
sDob=pygame.mixer.Sound('mintak2/drum_tom_lo_soft.wav')
while True:
    button.when_pressed = sDob.play
```

There is around half second latency between the press of the button and the play of the sound.

Comment: Found the solution on another stackexchange forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273722/pygame-sound-delay
Decreasing the buffer solves the latency problem:
pygame.mixer.init(22100, -16, 2, 64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to constantly assigned the `when_pressed` attribute (that'll actually cause a lot of work behind the scenes). Simply assign it once, then execute `pause()` to leave the script waiting on termination (i.e. `Ctrl+C`):

```
import pygame.mixer
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

pygame.mixer.init()
button = Button(3)
sDob = pygame.mixer.Sound('mintak2/drum_tom_lo_soft.wav')
button.when_pressed = sDob.play
pause()
```

As you've also noted in your comments, you can also tweak the [pygame mixer defaults](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.pre_init), so the complete script would look like this with your fix in it:

```
import pygame.mixer
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

pygame.mixer.pre_init(
    frequency=22100, size=-16, channels=2,
    buffersize=64)
pygame.mixer.init()
button = Button(3)
sDob = pygame.mixer.Sound('mintak2/drum_tom_lo_soft.wav')
button.when_pressed = sDob.play
pause()
```

(I added keyword args for readability)